# Spark Scala: retrieve the schema and store it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to retrieve the schema of an RDD and store it in a variable? Because I want to create a new data frame from another RDD using the same schema. For example, below is what I am hoping to have:

```
val schema = oldDF.getSchema()
val newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
```

Assuming I already have `rowRDD` in the format of `RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` , is this something possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `schema` attribute

```
val oldDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1))))
val rowRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(Row("b", 2))

sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, oldDF.schema)
```